# Need to create a django photo album

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am doing a project which require user photo upload and album creation ( like facebook photo album ) ,where one user can upload multiple photos in one album , can upload multiple album. After so search I found django imagestore app is handy enough. But unfortunately I did not find any example ore tutorial of imagestore.I am very new in django. Need some example tutorial about this app..Can you suggest better way to create a photo album?

This is my approach of creating an photo album -

```
def img_file_upload_path(instance, filename):
    """ creates unique-Path & filename for upload """
    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    filename = "%s%s.%s" % ('img', instance.pk, ext)

    return os.path.join(
        'images','eventpic','original',                                                      
        instance.event_id.channel_id.publisher.user.username, 
        instance.event_id.channel_id.channel_title, 
        instance.event_id.event_title, 
        filename
    )   

def formatted_img_file_upload_path(instance, filename):
    """ creates unique-Path & filename for upload """
    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    filename = "%s%s.%s" % ('img', instance.pk, ext)

    return os.path.join(
        'images','eventpic','formatted', 
        instance.event_id.channel_id.publisher.user.username, 
        instance.event_id.channel_id.channel_title, 
        instance.event_id.event_title,
        filename
    )    

def thumb_img_file_upload_path(instance, filename):
    """ creates unique-Path & filename for upload """
    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    filename = "%s%s.%s" % ('img', instance.pk, ext)

    return os.path.join(
        'images','eventpic','thumb', 
        instance.event_id.channel_id.publisher.user.username, 
        instance.event_id.channel_id.channel_title, 
        instance.event_id.event_title,
        filename
    )    

class Album(models.Model):
    album_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    event_id = models.ForeignKey(event_archive,db_column='event_id')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    summary = models.TextField()
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class Photo(models.Model):  
    image_id            = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    album               = models.ForeignKey(Album,db_column='album_id')
    title               = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    summary             = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_created        = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_modified       = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_cover_photo      = models.BooleanField()
    original_image      = models.ImageField(upload_to=img_file_upload_path) 

    def save(self):
        if self.is_cover_photo:
            other_cover_photo = Photo.objects.filter(album=self.album).filter(is_cover_photo = True)
            for photo in other_cover_photo:
                photo.is_cover_photo = False
                photo.save()
        filename = self.img_file_upload_path()
        if not filename == '':
            img = Image.open(filename)
            if img.mode not in ("L", "RGB"):
                img = img.convert("RGB")

            img.resize((img.size[0], img.size[1] / 2),Image.ANTIALIAS)
            img.save(self.formatted_img_file_upload_path(),quality=90)
            img.thumbnail((150,150), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            img.save(self.thumb_img_file_upload_path(),quality=90)
        super(Photo, self).save()


    def delete(self):
        filename = self.img_file_upload_path()
        try:
            os.remove(self.formatted_img_file_upload_path())
            os.remove(self.thumb_img_file_upload_path())
        except:
            pass
        super(Photo, self).delete()

    def get_cover_photo(self):
        if self.photo_set.filter(is_cover_photo=True).count() > 0:
            return self.photo_set.filter(is_cover_photo=True)[0]
        elif self.photo_set.all().count() > 0:
            return self.photo_set.all()[0]
        else:
            return None
```

The error in here which I could not fix is

```
 filename = self.img_file_upload_path()
```

Need help to fix the error.Do you think the approach is ok of creating an facebook like photoalbum?or should I use imagestore app?Here I have wanted to mention that I want to save the formatted image and thumb image keep while uploading..Need your expert review and help.

Comment: While I upload a photo this eroor occured after submit..Exception Type:  AttributeError
Exception Value:  

'Photo' object has no attribute 'img_file_upload_path'

Answer (score 0):

Even without seeing a traceback, I am pretty sure your error is occurring because you are trying to call methods that do not exist on you `Photo` model:

```
def img_file_upload_path(instance, filename):
def formatted_img_file_upload_path(instance, filename):
def thumb_img_file_upload_path(instance, filename):
```

These are just functions you have defined, and assigned as the `upload_to` handles for determining path upload path of a newly saved Image file. They do not live on your class. In order for you to be able to call them manually, you would have to do something like:

```
filename = img_file_upload_path(self, 'original_name.jpg')
```

Assuming `original_image` is properly set, it might be like:

```
if self.original_image.name:
    filename = img_file_upload_path(self, self.original_image.name)
```

Comment: curious to know whether my approach is ok to create a user based photo album??DO you have any tips??I found imagestore app but could not find any tutorial about this??Shall I use django imagestore app??

Comment: I am not really sure what the best approach would be, since I have not yet had to create one. I would probably just research what options exist already and check how active their development is. There is no point in reinventing the wheel. If a well maintained django app exists, why not use it?